# "aufhören mit" with "wollen" or a modal verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammatical-case, grammaticality

We could say "Er will nicht mehr unbedingt erfolgreich sein." Say we want to use "aufhören", are those sentences grammatically correct ?

> Er hört damit auf, unbedingt erfolgreich sein zu wollen.

> Er hört auf, auf jeden Preis Erfolg haben zu wollen.

Is "aufhören" indeed appropriate here ?

Comment: The correct preposition for Preis in this context is um, so the second sentence should read: Er hört auf, um jeden Preis Erfolg zu haben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both are appropriate and idiomatic. A very typical use of this is

> Ich habe (damit) aufgehört, um jeden Preis Erfolg haben zu wollen.

Present tense is less common, maybe because this is not an instantaneous thing that one does, but it's completely possible.

Grammatically, just note that it's ***um** jeden Preis*.

Answer (score 0):

"auf jeden Preis" has to be replaced by "um jeden Preis", apart from that both sentences are correct. However, in my opinion it would be better to say

> Er gibt es auf, unbedingt erfolgreich sein zu wollen.

> Er gibt es auf, um jeden Preis Erfolg haben zu wollen.